# How to print first 20 lines from file using cut command

Tags: shell-script

I have a file which contain 100 lines of text
from that I need to print only first 20 lines

how to print using only cut command

Comment: you mean `head -20 file` ? `cut` is not the right tool for this task.

Comment: @Archemar the task is like that i need to get it using cut command only , i know we can make use of sed -n 1,20p

Comment: Tell your 'teacher' that you will show them how to use `cut` to display the first 20 lines of a file after they show you how to use `fdisk` to display the last 20 lines of a file.

Answer (score 7):

With some `cut` implementations (including GNU's and busybox), you can do:

```
cut -d'
' -f1-20 < your-file
```

(that's on two lines, so as to have a newline character inside the `'...'` quotes; with shells that support the ksh93-style `$'...'` quotes, you can use `-d$'\n'` instead).

But that's neither standard nor portable.

It's also not documented and looks like an accident of implementation, so it could very well stop working without notice in future versions.

In the case of GNU and busybox `cut` at least, it also reads the input fully, so on the output of `yes` for instance, would never finish.

The right tool for that task is `head`:

```
head -n 20 < your-file
```

Though you could also use `sed`:

```
sed 20q < your-file
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '{print}; NR == 20 {exit}' < your-file
```

Comment: Is using `-d$'\n'` any more portable?

Comment: @terdon, no that would be less portable. The portability issue is about using newline as the field delimiter.

Comment: so `cut -d$'\n' -f-20` is expected answer ?